# How to detect if chrome is prompting the user for giving permissions to a quicktime plugin

Tags: google-chrome, audio, quicktime

As of a while ago, Chrome prompts the user to allow quicktime on a per-site basis. Since the app that I'm working on depends on quicktime, and I've seen a usage pattern in my users in that they often don't notice the browser prompting them to allow quicktime permissions to run on the site.

I would like to detect when Chrome/Any other browser is prompting the user for Quicktime permissions and display a more prominent message directing them to take action. Is there any way to do that?